# Map inside map async await

Tags: node.js, async-await, promise

I have to imbricate map using `async/await`.

I would like to know, if I wait the main `Promise.all`, will it also wait for the imbricated promises ?

```js
const upsertPromises = body.schedules.map(async schedule => {
    const createdSchedule = await this.addSchedule(briefId, schedule.week_day.id)
    schedule.exclusions.map(async exclusion => {
        await this.addScheduleExclusions(createdSchedule.id, exclusion.from.id, exclusion.to.id)
    })
})
await Promise.all(upsertPromises)
```

On this code, are the `this.addScheduleExclusions` done after lastline `Promise.all(upsertPromises)`?

Comment: `.map()` is only meaningful if its functor returns something, so add a couple or returns ... one inside each functor. `upsertPromises` will then be an array or arrays of promises. If you are interested only in completion rather than values, then simply await (or return) `Promise.all(upsertPromises.flat())` (you may need polyfill for .flat()).

Answer (score 0):

If all promises inside async function have `await` before them, then the async function will:

- resolve when all awaited resolved
- reject if any  awaited rejected.

If you run this function with `array.map` you will get promises that will resolve or not.

`Promise.all` will return promise that will do one of:

- resolve array of results if all resolved
- --  or  --
- reject with first error that rejected

```js
const upsertPromises = body.schedules.map(async schedule => {
    // awaited - ok
    const createdSchedule = await this.addSchedule(briefId, schedule.week_day.id)
    
    // Not awaited! 
    // schedule.exclusions.map( async exclusion => {
    // - need to add another `await` here like this:

    await Promise.all(schedule.exclusions.map( async exclusion => {
        // awaited - ok
        await this.addScheduleExclusions(
            createdSchedule.id, exclusion.from.id, exclusion.to.id
        )
    })
})

await Promise.all(upsertPromises)
```